# Visual Studio SDK. Получить выделенный класс в command

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, sdk

Хочу сделать расширение для Студии - создание шаблона на основе класса.
Класс выбираю нажатием правой кнопкой мыши в редакторе кода и выбрав нужную команду.

Вопрос:
Как получить в команде выбранный класс?